# error function integration $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x \operatorname{erf}(a x ) }{x^2+y^2} dx $

Tags: error-function

I'm interested in the following integral,
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x \operatorname{erf}(a x ) }{x^2+y^2} dx
$$
where, $\operatorname{erf}$ is error function. Does the analytical solution exist to this integral?

Comment: Care to add some context?

Comment: As Per Mathematica the integral does not converge.!

Comment: Note that $\mathrm{erf}$ is bounded on the real line, whence the integrand behaves like $1/x$ for large positive $x$, i.e., the integral diverges.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Others have said the integral does not converge, so do not treat this as a converged solution**. If we treat this **formally** only, take the Mellin transform of the integrand with respect to $a$ to a new parameter $s$ to get
$$
  -\frac{x^{1-s} \Gamma \left(\frac{s}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\right)}{\sqrt{\pi } s
    \left(x^2+y^2\right)}$$
if we integrate this with your range we get
$$
\text{ConditionalExpression}\left[-\frac{\sqrt{\pi }
    \left(\frac{1}{y^2}\right)^{s/2} \csc \left(\frac{\pi  s}{2}\right) \Gamma
    \left(\frac{s+1}{2}\right)}{2 s},(s-2) \arg \left(\frac{1}{y^2}\right)\geq
    -2 \pi \land \Re(s)<2\land \left(\Re\left(y^2\right)\geq 0\lor y^2\notin
    \mathbb{R}\right)\right]
$$
dropping the conditions (warning this might make everything invalid) gives
$$
-\frac{\sqrt{\pi } \left(\frac{1}{y^2}\right)^{s/2} \csc \left(\frac{\pi
    s}{2}\right) \Gamma \left(\frac{s+1}{2}\right)}{2 s}
$$
The inverse Mellin transform of this (from $s$ to $a$) gives an expression with hypergeometric function and digamma function, as well as erfi:
$$
 \frac{1}{2} \left(2 a^2 y^2 \, _2F_2\left(1,1;\frac{3}{2},2;a^2
    y^2\right)-\pi  \sqrt{\frac{1}{y^2}} y \;\text{erfi}(a y)+2 \log (a)-\log
    \left(\frac{1}{y^2}\right)-\psi ^{(0)}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\right)
$$
which might be a place to look for analytic continuation or formal solutions in terms of series etc.